# Page Processor is not working

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

processors.py file:

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from mezzanine.pages.page_processors import processor_for
from .models import Author

class AuthorForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

@processor_for(Author)
def author_form(request, page):
    form = AuthorForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form processing goes here.
            redirect = request.path + "?submitted=true"
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
    return {"form": form}
```

here define urls.py file where i define processor like:

```
url("^xyz/$", "mezzanine.pages.views.page", {"slug": "Author"},  name="Author"),
```

The form still doesn't display. How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mistake: Always define processor name in " " like @processor_for("Author")**

```
   **@processor_for("Author")** 

    def author_form(request, page):
        form = AuthorForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # Form processing goes here.
                redirect = request.path + "?submitted=true"
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
        return {"form": form}
```